# LPDIRECT3DDEVICE::DrawPrimitiveUP only drawing in black and white

Tags: c++, line, direct3d, primitive, direct3d9

```
struct tri_vertex 
{ 
    float x, y, z, h;
    D3DCOLOR color;
};

void Draw2DLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, D3DCOLOR dwColor)
{
    tri_vertex vertices[2] = 
    {
        x1, y1, 0.0f, 1.0f, dwColor,
        x2, y2, 0.0f, 1.0f, dwColor,
    };

    pDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_LINELIST, 1, vertices, sizeof(tri_vertex));
} 


pDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE );
pDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING, false ); 
pDevice->SetTexture( NULL, NULL );
pDevice->SetPixelShader( NULL );

// If commented out, the block drawn is black. Otherwise its completely white.
pDevice->SetVertexShader( NULL );

// For transparency 
pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND,D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND,D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP,D3DBLENDOP_ADD);

pDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1);
```

I am attempting to draw a simple line using DrawPrimitiveUP().
However the line drawn is either completely black or white depending on the SetVertexShader being nulled. It also doesn't support transparency in either.

Answer (score 0):

> However the line drawn is either completely black or white depending
>   on the SetVertexShader being nulled

What do you expected? colored line? Have you set the line color?

> It also doesn't support transparency in either.

You set the texture to null, so the blend has no effect to the line.

Comment: Yes the color has been set. It supports transparency in other D3D applications with the texture set to null.

Comment: where did you set the colors? I am very int interest in the transparent line, can you show me a picture of that?

Comment: Its set from the parameter of Draw2DLine()

Comment: Would you like to provide a compileable code? I want to have a try. currently I can't figure out anything wrong with the code you provided.